# Google Apps Script how to export specific sheet as csv format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In MIT Inventor II, I use web component to get SpreadsheetID and SheetID through doGet() of google apps script. After I get the information I use another web component to set url as below to get csv-formatted file from specific sheet. My question is how to make GAS to get SpreadsheetID & SheetID and then export csv file at one time, so that I don't have to use 2 web components in Inventor side?

GAS codes is as below. This is to "return" spreadsheetID and sheetID.

```
function doGet(e) {

filename = e.parameter.account;

fileList = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);

while (fileList.hasNext()) {
var fileID = fileList.next().getId()
    }

var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID) ;

   sheet = file.getSheetByName("Message").activate()

  var messageID = sheet.getSheetId();  

return ContentService.createTextOutput([fileID,messageID]);
```

After I got SpreadsheetID & SheetID, I have to set 2nd web component from Inventor side to get csv file, see below.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxSpreadsheetIDxxxx/edit#gid=sheetID
```

Comment: Can you show your `doGet()`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how you can create a csv file of a selected sheet in google drive:

```
function sheetToCsv()
{
    var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
    var sheet_Name = "Sheet1"
  
  
    var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet_Name)
      var sheetNameId = sheet.getSheetId().toString();
  
      params= ssID+"/export?gid="+sheetNameId +"&format=csv"
      var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ params
      var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData);  
  
   var resource = {
  title: sheet_Name+".csv",
  mimeType: "application/vnd.csv"
     }
   var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource,result)
  
}
```

The code creates a csv file that has the content of **Sheet1**.

In order to run the aforementioned function you need to activate the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).

Explanation:

Go to **Resources** => **Advanced Google Services** => *activate* **Drive API**

Another option is to create the csv file to a **particular folder**, then you need to replace the resource part of the code with this:

```
var folder_id ='id';
       
   var resource = {
  title: sheet_Name+".csv",
  mimeType: "application/vnd.csv",
  parents: [{ id: folder_id }]
     }
```

Comment: Where does the file goes? I could not find "Sheet1.csv" file in my drive either Google Drive or Drive in my notebook.

Comment: It is created in your drive (My Drive), with the name Sheet1.csv. However, see also my updated answer in which I added code to create a csv file to a particular folder. Check again if you have enabled Drive from resources.

Comment: Could not find the "Sheet1.csv" in MyDrive. Not sure if it's correct to past your codes after my codes, I also tried to use your codes only.. Can it be save to my Inventor by using like this, "return ContentService.createTextOutput([fileID,messageID]);"

Comment: See again my updated answer, you can choose the folder you want , to paste the data .

Comment: I've input folder ID, but still nothing..                     
  var folder_id ="1gCPxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCirhmbPzq"; 
  
  var resource = {
  title: sheet_Name+".csv",
  mimeType: "application/vnd.csv"
   }
   var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource,result);

Comment: share the error you are getting or any messages (i.a.)

Comment: Works now. Found 2 things, 1) when paste your code, it miss some semicolons ";" , 2) My original GAS was added from " + New" of MyDrive, not Tools --> Script editor...

Comment: If we use mimeType: MimeType.CSV then the file is recognisable by Google Drive as well.

Comment: MimeType.CSV is a good tip!

Answer (score 0):

My application was how to save a tab of a Google sheets spreadsheet to a CSV file in a **shared** drive. Doing it to the default "My Drive" was relatively easy based on [Marios' answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63266553/445963), but I struggled with this for a shared drive while until I came across [ziganotschka's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11599789/ziganotschka) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62468622/4060213) which solved my problem.

Code for my simple App Script is:

```
function sheetToCsv()
{
var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var sheet_Name = "[Your sheet name goes here]";

var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet_Name);
var sheetNameId = sheet.getSheetId().toString();

params= ssID+"/export?gid="+sheetNameId +"&format=csv";
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ params;
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData);  

var resource = {
  title: sheet_Name+".csv",
  mimeType: "MimeType.CSV",
  parents:[{
  "id": "[Your Shared Drive Folder ID goes here]"
      }]
    }

var optionalArgs={supportsAllDrives: true};

var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource, result, optionalArgs);

}
```

I added a timestamp to the file name and a trigger to cause the script to execute daily via a timer.

Comment: This seems to result in error:  `ReferenceError: ScriptApp is not defined`