# Export csv from Google sheet into "Shared Drives" not "My Drives"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have taken the script [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265983/google-apps-script-how-to-export-specific-sheet-as-csv-format) Which works perfectly when exporting to a folder in "My Drive" but if I try exporting it to folder in a "Shared drive" I get this error:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: File not found: 1ENj9R......

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, please include `supportsAllDrives` to the query parameter. When the script in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63265983) is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
 var resource = {
title: sheet_Name+".csv",
mimeType: "application/vnd.csv"
parents: [{ id: folder_id }]
   }
 var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource,result)
```

#### To:

```
var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID of your shared Drive.
var resource = {
  title: sheet_Name + ".csv",
  mimeType: MimeType.CSV,
  parents: [{id: folderId}]
}
var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource, result, {supportsAllDrives: true});
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that you have the permission for writing the file in the shared Drive. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)