# Create folder in Shared drive instead of local drive - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

I have found a script that works for my purpose of merging CSV's into one file, however I want to run this from a shared drive.

Is it possible to modify this script to use a shared drive instead?

The script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/import-csv-sheets

I've read through the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create) and enabled the Advanced Drive Service but sadly I think this is a bit beyond me.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post everything required to answer the question in the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464363/app-script-to-create-folders-fails-to-run-in-shared-drive